# Symfony 2 Entity form fields name

Tags: php, symfony

i have form builder:

```
        private function createTaskForm($id) {

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->setAction($this->generateUrl('admin_user__tasks_update_', array('id' => $id)))
                ->setMethod('put');
        $form
                ->add('tasks', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'WorksheetsWorksheetsBundle:Task',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'expanded' => 'true',
                    'multiple' => 'true'
                        )
        );
        return $form->getForm();
    }
```

but i need get every single child in controller, but i dont know how i can do this (dont know child name) because symfony generate this checkbox

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="form_tasks_27" name="form[tasks][]" value="27" />
```

Every field has this same name, how i can change this name in controller?

Comment: why do you want to get every child ? for a javascript action ? it would be easier if you provide more information ... but for a quick answer , in php checkbox returns you an array which contains all checkbox values ...

Comment: Before i send to view i must check some checkboxes.I need get every child value and compare this with other varible, if true set checked attribute if not, no.

Comment: so you can directly do this inside your form class with, if your variables are inside you database, a query builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't how Symfony works. With the Symfony framework building a form sets up a mapping between the form (view) and it's underlying data (model). You work with the data. Symfony maps the data to the form and back automatically. To set defaults into a form you modify the underlying form data, not the form's view elements themselves.

By default, the underlying data for a form is an associative array. So you might do something like this before the last line of your method to check the tasks with ids 2, 3 and 5:

```
...
$em = $this->get('doctrine)->getManager();
$taskRepo = $em->getRepository('WorksheetsWorksheetsBundle:Task');
$data['tasks'][] = $taskRepo->findOneById(2);
$data['tasks'][] = $taskRepo->findOneById(3);
$data['tasks'][] = $taskRepo->findOneById(5);
$form->setData($data);
...
```

Note I wouldn't recommend actually hard-coding the default task id's in that method like this.

Also bear in mind that to get the most out of Symfony you would typically set a form up to map to a particular class of entity. In this case that would be the entity that has many tasks and it would have a data member 'tasks' with corresponding add and remove methods. By using the entity as the form's underlying data, any tasks belonging to the entity would automatically be checked on the form and the entity's tasks would automatically be updated by $form->handleRequest(). Again, if you need to set default values, you can then do so by setting then on the entity before you pass it into the form as data. If the values are not defaults but the actual values already belonging to the entity then you don't need to do anything. I strongly recommend using this approach.